# How to update jira issue using rest API(json)

Tags: java, apache, httpclient, jira-rest-java-api

**I need to update jira issue using java code **

> Following code im using

```
 String url ="http://IP/rest/api/latest/issue/test-6120";
    String auth = new String(Base64.encode("test:test"));
    String data ="{\"fields\":{\"reporter\":{\"name\":\"vishnuk\"}}}";


 {
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
    ClientResponse response = webResource.header("Authorization", "Basic " + auth).type("application/json")
            .accept("application/json").put(ClientResponse.class, data);
    int statusCode = response.getStatus();

}
    System.out.print(statusCode);
}
```

Above this code im getting  204 http error

Can someone tell me what is the wrong i did and what correction i have to do

Comment: 204 is not an error.  https://httpstatuses.com/204

Comment: ya what is the solution for this case

Comment: this is not an error, when you check the documentation it says; `STATUS 204 Returned if the transition was successful.`